# How to publish the testNG reports in azure devops pipeline ? is there any extensions for same?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, allure, azure-devops-extensions

Getting blank page in Allure report tab under the Azure Devops build.
As per the log, the report has been generated. Can someone please tell me what is the issue here?

This is the information I am using for Allure Task :
[image: Allure Task]

Task I have added :

[image: Other task, I have added]

Answer (score 0):

> How to publish the testNG reports in azure devops pipeline ? is there any extensions for same?

Azure DevOps does not support testNG test results format.

And testNG also produces JUnit test results in a separate junitreports folder. So, we can publish TESTNG test results in JUnit format instead.

You could use the `Publish Test Results` task to publish the reports.
Please select the “JUnit” Test result format and change the `Test results files` as `**/junitreports/TEST-*.xml`.

You could check my provious thread for some more details:

[How to integrate TestNG or Extent reports with Azure devops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677823/how-to-integrate-testng-or-extent-reports-with-azure-devops)

But for the extension Allure Test Reports task, there are many communities report the same issue on the Q&A for this task:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Molecula.allure-test-reports&ssr=false#qna

This issue should be more related to this extension, you could check the Q&A for the feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Referring to the documentation for [Allure Test Reports](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ivang7.allure-test-reports&targetId=06e2de9d-0560-4fd5-8c72-c3d0e7d69fa6).

> To enable "Open Allure Report" option you will need to add additional build step to **publish the report somewhere**. For instance you can create a simple Azure Web App and upload reports there using Build Task extension like FTP Upload. Your website should support HTTPS.